# Filtering dataframe based on two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe `df` like so

```
food    color   popular
apple   red     no
pear    green   no
banana  yellow  yes
apple   red     yes
```

How do i get nonduplicate rows based on only two columns (food & color)?

Expected result:

```
food    color   popular
pear    green   no
banana  yellow  yes
```

I tried:

```
df %>% distinct(food, color, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

but this doesn't give me my expected result

Comment: We could use `duplicated` i.e. `df[!duplicated(df[ ,c(1, 2)]), ]`

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)

# Create test data
df = tibble(
    food=c("apple", "pear", "bananna", "apple"),
    color=c("red", "green", "yellow", "red"),
    popular=c(F, F, T, T)
)

df %>%
    # Make a group for each combination of food and colour
    group_by(food, color) %>%
    # Then delete any group with more than 1 element
    # (since they are duplicates)
    filter(n() == 1) %>%
    ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  food    color  popular
  <chr>   <chr>  <lgl>  
1 pear    green  FALSE  
2 bananna yellow TRUE
```